# Examples of uniformly discrete proper metric spaces which are not countable.

Tags: metric-spaces

By uniformly discrete I mean there exists a $C > 0$ such that for all $x \neq y$ we have $d(x, y) \geq C$. By proper I mean the preimage of every closed ball is compact.

Are there any examples of such spaces which are uncountable?

Comment: Consider $(\mathbb R,d)$ which: $d(x,y)=1+|x-y|$ for $x\neq y$.

Comment: @hamidkamali That one is not proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every such space is at most countable. Fix $a\in X$ and write $X$ as $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{B}(a,n)$. Since $X$ is proper, $\overline{B}(a,n)$ is compact. But it is also discrete, therefore finite. (An infinite compact set would have a limit point, contradicting discreteness).